# Print matrix closing codeblocks

Tags: c, matrix

What's wrong in the code below?
Codeblocks closes when i try to run it, why? I need to create a matrix with 700 rows and 50 column and fill with words. Is it possible using static matrix or the dinamic one? Won't it cause stack overflow because of it's size?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
int i,j;
char mat_palavras[100][100];


    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        for(j=0; j<100; j++){
          mat_palavras[i][j]= 'i';
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        for(j=0; j<100; j++){
          printf("%s\n" ,mat_palavras[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are telling `printf` to display a string, not a character.  That means it expects a pointer.  Use `%c` instead of `%s`.

Comment: In Windows the default stack size is 1MB for each process.

Comment: And   for "700 rows and 50 column" Why you are taking a 2D array of [100][100] and not of [700][50] ??

Comment: @H2CO3 try to understand that everyone must learn this material from the start.  No one is a born knowing this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line causes the problem

```
printf("%s\n" ,mat_palavras[i][j]);
```

Instead of `%s`, use `%c`.

Answer (score 0):

It can work well now.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
int i,j;
char mat_palavras[105][105]; //expand your 2D-array's size


    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        for(j=0; j<100; j++){
          mat_palavras[i][j]= 'i';
        }
        mat_palavras[i][j] = '\0'; //Add this statement, '\0' is the end mark of string
    }
    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        //for(j=0; j<100; j++){ //Delete this statement
          printf("%s\n" ,mat_palavras[i]);
        //}
    }
}
```